# Stupidly simple javascript won't run

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble with a stupidly simple problem. I have an HTMl file that has successfully hooked up to a css file, but ever time I try something easy in Javascript, it doesn't do it. All of my files are in the same folder. I am running this off of Notepad ++

enter code here

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
                        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="header">
                    </div>

                    <div class="main">
                        <div id="comic"></div>
                        <div id="caption"></div>
                        <div id="prompt">
                            <h3>Hello, world!</h3>
                        <div class="btn" id="yes"><img src="YESsmall.jpg"/></div>
                        <div class="btn" id="no"><img src="NOsmall.jpg"/></div>
                    </div>


                </body>
            </html>
```

And my Javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main').hide();
});
```

what on earth have I done wrong?

Comment: are you loading in jQuery anywhere? $ is not native js code

Comment: have you included jQuery? can't see it anywhere... (or is it in script.js?)

Comment: That isn't "simple JavaScript", it is jQuery.

Comment: If you'd opened your console, the hint would've been `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 3):

I don't see you loading jQuery (or anything else providing a `$`). You can use a jQuery provided by a content delivery network ([as described here](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-39-s-cdn-provided-by-maxcdn)) by adding

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

(or similar, depending on what version you need/want) before your other `<script>`